# How change the color of points in ggplot and in the legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hi all I want to change the colors of the points and legend scale bar of this PCA plot.

Points and legend bar should be colored from white to red according to the individuals column in the dataframe pca.df2.

here is my code:

```
pca.df2
         PC1         PC2    site     individuals
1  -0.07922025 -0.24879390  Site_1           1
2  -0.06970641 -0.37429438  Site_2           3
3   0.38358670  0.30458278  Site_3           1
4  -0.09439335 -0.24342483  Site_3           7
5   0.54806164  0.37773392  Site_3           6
6   0.37652793  0.18787613  Site_4         100
7   0.33063539  0.19714456  Site_5          11
8  -0.07499824 -0.36179320  Site_6           2
9  -0.06852176 -0.31423777  Site_6          13
10 -0.11814155  0.88044154  Site_7           2
11 -0.06179955 -0.30741536  Site_8           6
12 -0.04988480 -0.51273423  Site_8          15
13 -0.05511221 -0.32341246  Site_8           1
14 -0.07670205 -0.29447917  Site_8           3
15 -0.05859276 -0.36255447  Site_9          13
16 -0.58016416  0.30205834 Site_10          20
17 -0.60372749  0.33624664 Site_10          20
18  0.50309937  0.18595340 Site_11           0
19  0.52359160  0.21650885 Site_11           0
20  0.47277134  0.23660837 Site_11           0
21  0.07808164  0.82686966 Site_12           0
22  0.39600791  0.26408474  Site_3           1
23 -0.58463995  0.30759417  Site_3           1
24 -0.09371119 -0.38795664  Site_3           0
25 -0.06315584 -0.43697666  Site_9           0
26 -0.08363540 -0.49415554  Site_9           0
27  0.58200297  0.05087838  Site_9           0
28 -0.08260636 -0.51948546  Site_9           0
29  0.50746161  0.28305792 Site_10         100
30  0.51484230  0.26648235 Site_10          20
31  0.50018288  0.27403934 Site_10          10
32  0.65213830  0.22979153 Site_10           0
33 -0.60171616  0.41369022  Site_9           5
34 -0.07769504 -0.28474221  Site_2          11
35 -0.09362310 -0.20762404  Site_4         100
36 -0.57234586  0.36915225 Site_14           0
37 -0.07276762 -0.18798218 Site_10         100
38 -0.60075123  0.41238360 Site_10         100
39 -0.07611488 -0.23506584  Site_6           0
40 -0.05729845 -0.27410771  Site_8           0
41 -0.43349977  0.10302564  Site_8           0
42 -0.07153716 -0.24794602  Site_7           0
43  0.17470213 -0.52990499  Site_1           0
44  0.15780482 -0.56123908  Site_5         100
45 -0.69455183  0.48925234  Site_5         100
46 -0.45088411  0.19486945  Site_5         100


PCA.Vec2
       PC1          PC2    site       individuals
 0.422715672 -0.206407473 Site_12           0
 0.232160138 -0.093285013 Site_12           0
-0.522126719 -0.464179730 Site_12           0
-0.062515290  0.223680102 Site_12           0
 0.462021465 -0.365494141 Site_12           0
-0.049973407  0.192220716 Site_12           0
-0.266727503 -0.138092559 Site_12           0
 0.018515638  0.077735215 Site_12           0
 0.031212309 -0.008060688 Site_12           0
-0.002688768 -0.145518833 Site_12           0
-0.229282173  0.107332059 Site_12           0
-0.080981840  0.006918153 Site_12           0

dca.vasc_2 <-ggplot(data = pca.df2, aes(x = PC1, y = PC2, color=individuals))+ theme_bw()+ 
  geom_point(size=5) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0,linetype ='dotted', color = "black") + geom_vline(xintercept = 0,linetype = 'dotted', color = "black")+
  geom_segment(data = PCA.Vec2, aes(x = 0, y = 0, xend = PC1, yend = PC2), arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.2, "cm")),colour="red") +
  scale_fill_gradient(low ="white", high = "red", guide = guide_colorbar(frame.colour = "black", ticks.colour = "black"))

dca.vasc_2 + labs(x = "PC1 (0.5341)", y = "PC2 (0.3391)",title = "PCA")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5,size=20),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size=15, face = "bold"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size=15, face = "bold"), 
        axis.title=element_text(size=15,face="bold"), 
        panel.background = element_rect(fill="white",linetype="solid"),
        panel.grid.major = element_line(size = 0.5, linetype = "solid", colour = "grey"), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_line(size = 0.25, linetype = "solid",colour = "grey"))
```

Here is the plot I get with my code but the color is just from darkblue to lightblue,
How can i change this?
[image]

Comment: Change `scale_fill_gradient` to `scale_color_gradient`